# Webscraping multiple tags from in a single site from multiple websites

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am attempting to scrape data from multiple webpages that have multiple iterations of various tags. See the example below.

I've been able to pull the data from the webpage and store the first iteration of the table tags however I'm not able to pull the rest of the tags. I'm sure I need another for loop somewhere but I'm not sure where to add it if thats what is required.

```
df_list = []
folder = 'camupdate'
for cam_data in os.listdir(folder):
    with open(os.path.join(folder, cam_data),encoding="utf8") as file:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(file)
        title = soup.find('title').contents[0]
        main_title = soup.find('div', id_='login_inputs')
        tag = soup.find('div', class_='tag_row')
        tag_title = tag.find('span').contents
        viewers = tag.find_all('span')[1].contents
        rooms = tag.find_all('span')[2].contents
        df_list.append({'title': title,
                        'main_title': main_title,
                        'tag_title': tag_title,
                        'viewers': viewers,
                        'rooms': rooms})

df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns = ['title','main_title', 'tag_title', 'viewers', 'rooms'])
```

Example of code:

```
# I am trying to pull from this tag, the page=1
<div id="login_inputs">
<form method='post' action='/auth/login/?next=/tags/?page=1' target="_top">

<a href="/tag/x1/" title="x1">x1</a>
</span>
<span class="viewers">48804</span>
<span class="rooms">550</span>

<div class="tag_row">
<span class="tag">
<a href="/tag/x2/" title="x2">x2</a>
</span>
<span class="viewers">22067</span>
<span class="rooms">400</span>

<a href="/tag/x3/" title="x3">x3</a>
</span>
<span class="viewers">12857</span>
<span class="rooms">253</span>

# I am trying to pull from this tag, the page=2
<div id="login_inputs">
<form method='post' action='/auth/login/?next=/tags/?page=2' target="_top">



<a href="/tag/y1/" title="y1">y1</a>
</span>
<span class="viewers">1425</span>
<span class="rooms">16</span>


<div class="tag_row">
<span class="tag">
<a href="/tag/y2/" title="y2">y2</a>
</span>
<span class="viewers">785</span>
<span class="rooms">32</span>

<a href="/tag/y3/" title="y3">y3</a>
</span>
<span class="viewers">492</span>
<span class="rooms">12</span>
```

Actual

```
    title   main_title  tag_title   viewers    rooms
0   Tags    None        x1          [48804]    [388]
1   Tags    None        y1          [1425]     [16]
```

Expected

```
    title   main_title  tag_title   viewers    rooms
0   Tags    Page 1      x1          [48804]    [550]
1   Tags    Page 1      x2          [22067]    [400]
3   Tags    Page 1      x3          [12857]    [253]
4   Tags    Page 2      y1          [1425]     [16]
5   Tags    Page 2      y2          [785]      [32]
6   Tags    Page 2      y3          [492]      [12]
```

Comment: Hey, I think this would be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) as you're primarily looking for advice on how to fix your implementation, not necessarily on how to accomplish something. I used the help center "https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic" to come to this conclusion.

Comment: Its a suggestion -i might be totally wrong . Would you want to do this - ```main_title = soup.find('div', id_='login_inputs')```    then ```main_title_text = main_title.text``` also get the ```page=2``` like page name values using a regex from within the URL str/ text .

Comment: Code review is for code that works as intended.

Comment: try soup.select_one('[method=post][action]')['action'].split('?')[1]   I also see no reference to _table_ tags (at least directly by _type_ )

Comment: @QHarr this generated an error: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "[method=post][action]"

Comment: Looks valid to me unless And syntax is only supported in later bs4 versions. What version are you using?

Comment: I updated the bs4 to make sure, but it's still giving me the same error.